# How do I enable "morph into" for custom widgets in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qtwidgets

I have a `CollapseGroupBox` that inherits `QGroupBox`, and shows up in the Qt Designer widget list.
It'd be nice if I could use the existing "Morph into ..." on existing `QGroupBox` instances, as there are a few.

But there's nothing in the docs and all I could find was [this sad post on the Qt forums](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64485/qtdesigner-customwidget-plugin-morph-into) with no replies. 
I haven't looked at the source yet though.:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looking for `Morph into` and not `Promote to...`? Because your class is inherting `QGroupBox` you should use `Promote to...` instead. Make sure that its constructor is identical to the one of `QGroupBox`, otherwise `Qt Creator` will not be able to generate the needed code for you.

Here's how you would do it. First right click and select `Promote to...`, then specify you class name and the header file where it is declared. And then click on `Add`.

[image]

Once you get to this screen, click on `Promote` and you're done:

[image]

Comment: Quite sure! :) .. I want to convert my class inside the designer, so I can see it directly. Promoting only changes the output in the .ui file and when running the real program.

Comment: Oh I see. That would have been too advanced:) I am guessing you want it so that Qt Designer will render it based on your modifications?